# Create Gtk composite object that doesn't have a container as a parent

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glib, gobject

As an example, I want to create a very simple Gtk composite object which is a GtkButton inside a GtkBox.  That's it.  Let's call it `BoxedButon`

But, I'd like it to have the interface of a GtkButton.  The same properties, signals, methods, etc.

If I derive a new class with a parent class of `GTK_TYPE_BUTTON`, then `GTK_BUTTON((BoxedButton*)a_boxed_button_instance)` will work.  It effectively has the interface of a button.

But it can't be added into a container, because when the `BoxedButton` is added it tries to add the `GtkWidget` corresponding to the `GtkButton`, which is already in the `GtkBox` that the `BoxedButton` also contains.

If the class is instead derived from a parent of `GTK_TYPE_BOX`, then adding it to a container works.  But it has none of the interface of a `GtkButton`.  Every property, signal, `gtk_button_*` method, etc. needs to be duplicated.  That's an order of magnitude more code than anything else the new class needs to do.

I thought maybe I could override `set_parent()`, so that it sets the box's parent instead.  But `GtkBoxClass` doesn't have a `set_parent()`, so apparently whatever happens to add a widget to a rendering hierarchy can't be overridden.

Is there some way to do this that doesn't involve hundreds of lines of code?

Comment: With your first solution : maybe you could cast to `GtkBox` before calling `add`?

Comment: It's not derived from `GtkBox`, so casting to that type doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe if there was a way to do multiple inheritance in gobject, it could be derived from both, but I think that's possible.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood. Its composition. Then maybe a getter for the GtkBox?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with two ways to do this, but neither seems ideal.

The first is to derive the composite widget from the object type we want to think of the composite object as a type of. In this case, we derive the object from `GtkButton` because we want to think of it as a type of button and inherit the interface of a buffer.  Then create an instance method to get whatever widget is the top level of the composite widget's layout hierarchy.  For example:

```
GtkWidget *boxed_button_get_toplevel(BoxedButton *bb)
{
    BoxedButtonPrivate *priv = boxed_button_get_instance_private(bb);
    return GTK_WIDGET(priv->top_level_box);
}
```

When adding the composite object to a container this method is used to get the object to add. E.g:

```
GtkWidget *bb = boxed_button_new();
gtk_container_add(some_container, boxed_button_get_toplevel(BOXED_BUTTON(bb)));
gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(bb), "Label");
```

This is simple to implement and use, but no other Gtk widget works this way.  The widget itself is always added to a container.

So we get another alternative, which is derive the object from the type of the top level container, e.g. from a `GtkBox`.  Then create an instance method to get the widget that we should think of the composite widget as a type of, e.g. `GtkButton.`  Now we have code more like this:

```
GtkButton *boxed_button_get_button(BoxedButton *bb)
{
    BoxedButtonPrivate *priv = boxed_button_get_instance_private(bb);
    return GTK_BUTTON(priv->contained_button);
}
GtkWidget *bb = boxed_button_new();
gtk_container_add(some_container), GTK_WIDGET(boxed_button_get_button(BOXED_BUTTON(bb))));
gtk_button_set_label(boxed_button_get_button(BOXED_BUTTON(bb)), "Label");
```

This is likely more trouble, since there are likely to be far more calls that use the composite as widget as a button than add it to a container.  There's also a significant drawback.  One can not add to or override properties or signals provided by `GtkButton`.  New properties and signals will be defined for the composite object, while `GtkButton` properties and signals will be defined by the button and can't be changed.

Comment: Your fisrt solution is the best one in my opinion. The simplest and most maintainable. Note that it is true that no other Gtk widget work this way, however no native Gtk widget is constructed this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there's a third way as well; inherit from GtkBox and proxy all the methods of GtkButton. This will be quite verbose in C and still not give you the convenience of using the GtkButton interface (you'd have to write `boxed_button_set_label(...)`) but if you were using your widget from language bindings, this would probably be the easiest way to go.